# Cannot activate Conda environment with fermitools

Tags: macos, terminal, conda

I am trying to activate a Conda environment that has fermitools (2.0.8) installed (see [docs](https://github.com/fermi-lat/Fermitools-conda/wiki/Installation-Instructions)) using command

```bash
conda activate fermi
```

After that it's showing me the message below. **How do I resolve the following errors?**

### System Details

- Mac OS terminal
- Mac OS Monterey 12.1

### Error Message

```bash
input_line_1:1:2: **error**: module 'Darwin' uses additional module map

'/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/mach_machine.modulemap'
      used when the module was built
#include <new> 

^

input_line_1:1:2: note: imported by module 'std' in '/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/std.pcm' 

Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():   Failed to extract C++ standard library version. 

Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():   Possible C++ standard library mismatch, compiled with _LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION '1'   Extraction of runtime standard library version was: '' input_line_2:1:2: **error**: module 'Darwin' uses additional module map
      '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/mach_machine.modulemap' used when the module was built
#include "cling/Interpreter/RuntimeUniverse.h"  
^ 

input_line_2:1:2: note: imported by module 'std' in '/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/std.pcm' 

input_line_2:1:2: note: imported by module 'Cling_Runtime' in
      '/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/Cling_Runtime.pcm' 
Failed to load module std 
Failed to load module std 
Failed to load module Cling_Runtime 

In file included from input_line_7:36: 
In file included from /opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/bin/../include/c++/v1/cassert:20: 
In file included from /opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/etc//cling/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/assert.h:8: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:69:26:

**error**: expected function body after function declarator void abort(void) __dead2 __cold;

                         ^

IncrementalExecutor::executeFunction: symbol '_ZN5cling7runtime6gClingE' unresolved while linking function '_GLOBAL__sub_I_cling_module_12'! You are probably missing the definition of cling::runtime::gCling Maybe you need to load the corresponding shared library?

 *** Break *** segmentation violation [/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib] _sigtramp (no debug info) [<unknown binary>] (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libCling.6.22.06.so] cling::Value::isVoid() const (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libCling.6.22.06.so] TCling::ProcessLine(char const*, TInterpreter::EErrorCode*) (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libRint.6.22.06.so] TRint::ProcessLineNr(char const*, char const*, int*) (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libRint.6.22.06.so] TRint::HandleTermInput() (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libCore.6.22.06.so] TUnixSystem::CheckDescriptors() (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libCore.6.22.06.so] TUnixSystem::DispatchOneEvent(bool) (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libCore.6.22.06.so] TSystem::InnerLoop() (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libCore.6.22.06.so] TSystem::Run() (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libCore.6.22.06.so] TApplication::Run(bool) (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/lib/libRint.6.22.06.so] TRint::Run(bool) (no debug info) 
[/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/bin/root.exe] main (no debug info) 
[/usr/lib/dyld] start (no debug info) 

IncrementalExecutor::executeFunction: symbol '_ZN5cling7runtime6gClingE' unresolved while linking [cling interface function]! You are probably missing the definition of cling::runtime::gCling
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing symbols usually imply that there is compiled code against a particular dynamic library, but you have installed a different build of that library. For Conda, this is usually caused by channel mixing, that is, installing the dynamic libraries from an Anaconda Cloud channel that isn't the same as the one used when building the package.

However, Monterey is rather new, so there may be something system-level that needs to be addressed. For example, new MacOS I think always requires a new XCode Command Line Tools installation. I wouldn't be surprised if you would need to download some older SDK that is not shipping by default with MacOS 12.

### Conda Channel Mixing

To debug things on the Conda side, one should look at what channels packages are being sourced from, i.e., `conda list -n fermi`. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/fermi-lat/Fermitools-conda/wiki/Installation-Instructions#installing-the-fermitools), the **conda-forge** channel should have highest priority, so I would expect nearly everything but the various `fermitools` packages to come from there.

Testing on **osx-64**, I have no issue following current documentation, except that one must have `channel_priority: flexible`:

```bash
## also, use mamba
CONDA_CHANNEL_PRIORITY mamba create -n fermi -c conda-forge -c fermi fermitools python=3 clhep=2.4.4.1
```

One could also dig down into where it is crashing in activation by looking at what is run for activation:

```
conda shell.posix activate fermi
```

which will list (without evaluation) all the commands run during activation.

But, I would just focus on getting a clean installation, with correct channels.

Comment: when I am opening .condarx file its showing only default in it and no Conda-forge what does that means??

Comment: @parthpatil that is a global configuration. If you used exactly the command stated in the documentation, Conda would prioritize the **conda-forge** channel.